# Show that the variance of the longitudinal estimate is $ \dfrac{2 \sigma^2(1-\rho)} { n} $ rather than $\dfrac{\sigma^2(\rho)}{n}$

Tags: variance, panel-data, exchangeability

> patients are randomızed to elther treatment, their pressures are measured at baseline, treatment is administered for two weeks and $\mathrm{BP}$ is then measured a second time. The treatment effect is estimated by the average change in $\mathrm{BP}$ for group A minus the average change for group $\mathrm{B}$.

> Suppose that BP measurements from distinct individuals are independent with variance $\sigma^2$ and that the correlation between repeated observations on a single individual is $\rho$. Then the variance of the longitudinal estimate is $$ 2 \sigma^2(1-\rho) / n .$$

I cannot understand why the variance of the longitudinal estimate is not $\dfrac{\sigma^2(\rho)}{n}$ and I do not understand the origin of the scalar multiplication by two.

https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.4780111406

Comment: Why do you think the variance should be $2\sigma^2\rho$?

Comment: The exchangeable $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon\epsilon^T]$ matrix is $\rho$ on all non-diagonal entries. $\mathbb{E}[\epsilon\epsilon^T]=\sigma^2\Omega=\Sigma$. I think the variance is in the $\Sigma$ and is found on a non-diagonal entry. @statmerkur

Comment: Let $\epsilon$ the residual of the regression model. $\Omega=cov(\epsilon|X)$ with X=data matrix.

Comment: @TransIndigenous AFAICS $2 \sigma^2(1-\rho) / n$ is the variance of the average change in BP for group $A$ or $B$, respectively. The variance of the longitudinal estimator of the treatment effect should be twice that quantity if we assume independence between the groups. See my answer for the derivation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $Var(X)=\sigma_X^2$ and $Var(Y)=\sigma_Y^2$ and $Cor(X,Y)=\rho$,

and assuming without loss of generality $E[X]=E[Y]=0$, so $E[X^2]=E[Y^2]=\sigma^2$,

then $Cov(X,Y)=E[XY]=\rho \sigma_X^{\,} \sigma_Y^{\,}$,

and thus $Var(X-Y)= E[(X-Y)^2]=E[X^2]-2E[XY]+E[Y^2]= \sigma_X^2 - 2\rho \sigma_X^{\,} \sigma_Y^{\,} +  \sigma_Y^2$.

If $\sigma_X^2=\sigma_Y^2 = \sigma^2$ we can simplify this to $Var(X-Y)=2(1-\rho)\sigma^2$.

In this question, that is the variance of the change in blood pressure of an individual.  The division by $n$ is to see the variance in the average change across $n$ individuals.

Answer (score 3):

The variance of the longitudinal estimator of the treatment effect should be
$$
\begin{align}
&\mathbb{V}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(X_{A,t_2,i}-X_{A,t_1,i}\right)-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n\left(X_{B,t_2,j}-X_{B,t_1,j}\right)\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}\left[\mathbb{V}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\left(X_{A,t_2,i}-X_{A,t_1,i}\right)\right)+\mathbb{V}\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\left(X_{B,t_2,j}-X_{B,t_1,j}\right)\right)\right] \\
&= 
\frac{1}{n^2} \cdot 2 \cdot  \left[ \mathbb{V}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_{A,t_2,i}\right) + \mathbb{V}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_{A,t_1,i}\right) - 2\cdot \operatorname{Cov}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_{A,t_2,i}, \sum_{i=1}^nX_{A,t_1,i}\right) \right] \\
&= 
\frac{2}{n^2} \left(n \cdot \sigma^2 + n \cdot \sigma^2 - 2 \cdot n \cdot \rho \cdot \sigma^2 \right) = \frac{2}{n}  \left(2 \cdot \sigma^2 - 2 \cdot \rho \cdot  \sigma^2 \right) \\
&= 
\frac{4}{n} \sigma^2 \left(1-\rho\right).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Your extra factor of $2$ is for the variance of the difference between the mean change in A and the mean change in B (i.e. difference-in-difference), while I suspect the original expression was just the variance for the mean change in one of them.

Comment: @Henry I agree with your variance of difference vs. variance of difference-in-differences remark, see my last comment to the OP's question. However, in the paper it says "The treatment effect [in the longitudinal design] is estimated by the average change in BP for group $A$ minus the average change for group $B$." and "[...] the variance of the cross-sectional estimate of the treatment effect is $2\sigma^2/n$ where $n$ is the number of persons in each group; the variance of the longitudinal estimate is $2\sigma^2(1 - \rho)/n$." So the original expression seems to be off by a factor of $2$.